# Re-send local notification in case of error

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

In our app, we send scheduled local notifications as reminders. There's a button on the notification to mark the reminder as completed. When we handle the local notification, we send an API request to mark the reminder as completed.

In the case of the HTTP request failing, we would like to re-send the local push notification for two reasons: 1) that the user knows the original action failed, 2) so that they can retry.

We tried sending a local notification in the `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:for:completionHandler` callback. We schedule the retry notification for ~5 seconds from the present time. It works on the simulator, but it doesn't work on an actual device.

I have tried adding `application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("showNotification", nil)` in the app's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions` method, and this does make it work on the device. However, I am concerned that it is not a robust solution. Our reminder notifications can be sent at any time of the day and the documentation for `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` says that it only works temporarily.

So my question is: Is there really no way to re-send a local notification on iOS? On the other hand, if there is, how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to use local notification in failure instead of execute the retry flow directly on failure handling block?

Comment: `We schedule the retry notification for ~5 seconds from the present time` Does app active at this time?

Comment: @piyuj we don't have our networking stack set up to do auto retries. additionally, the request is a POST which isn't idempotent

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev no, we schedule the retry notification while the app is in the background (the code is run in the local notification handler)

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
func showScheduledNotification() {
    backgroundTaskID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { [weak self] in
        guard let backgroundTaskID = self?.backgroundTaskID else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID)
    })
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        if let backgroundTaskID = strongSelf.backgroundTaskID {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTaskID)
            strongSelf.backgroundTaskID = nil
        }
        /* show notification */
        if /* showNotificationSuccess */ {
            return
        }
        strongSelf.showScheduledNotification()
    }
}
```

So, after each try, background task will be ended. And next will start after 5 sec if necessary.

Don't forget to add:

```
var backgroundTaskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
```